# Math.exp in Java calculates incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, java, math, exp

In Javascript, I tried `Math.exp(-1800/2000)` and the result is `0.4065696597405991`. However, in Java, the same function returns `1.0`? I read the documentations and Math.exp in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#exp-double-) and [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/exp) basically do the same thing.

In Java, Math.exp(a) returns:

> the value e^a, where e is the base of the natural logarithms. //in Java

In Javascript, Math.exp(x) returns:

> A number representing e^x, where e is Euler's number and x is the
>   argument.

Maybe it's just a beginner's mistake.

Comment: In java `-1800/2000` is 0. Not sure about Javascript. Try `-1800.0/2000`

Comment: I actually have this: `multiplier1 = Math.exp(-frequency/1300)*1700`. So apparently variable `frequency` of type `int` is the reason for the incorrectness.

Comment: Yes, I think that's it. I edited my answer to reflect your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, `-1800/2000` results in an integer (`0`). You need to cast to a suitable type (`double`).

Try:

```
Math.exp(-1800.0/2000.0)
```

Or in your case:

```
multiplier1 = Math.exp((double)-frequency / 1300.0) * 1700.0;
```

Comment: Ouch. Thanks @RobinTopper. Fixed.